# Create new dynamic id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this piece of code right here that creates somewhat of a grid (but not really) of chocolate pieces in x and y positions (height and length) depending on what the user chooses in the input, and i want it to assign a new id (preferably imgPos1, imgPos2 etc...) to each piece of chocolate it produces individually. I have tried referring to other posts but i am completely clueless.
I am open to any suggestions to third party frameworks (react etc).

**HTML (and js):**

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
  <form name='grid' id="grid">
<!-- Form to define the x size and y size of the grid made out of chocolate pieces -->
    Desired Length: <input type='number' name='length' min=1 max=10 step=1 value=1 id="lengthInput" />
    Desired Height: <input type='number' name='height' min=1 max=10 step=1 value=1 id="heightInput" />
    <input type='button' value='Apply' class="button_Change" />
  </form>
</div>
<div id='choc'></div>
  <template>
    <img id="imgPos" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Chocolate_Bar_Emoji_large.png?" onclick='removeMe(this)' class='visible'>
  </template>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  /* Script that creates the grid by cloning the chocolate image for x:length
  and y:height */

  // defines variables q,d,form using jquery
  const d = document;
  const q = (e, n = d) => n.querySelector(e);
  const form = d.forms.grid;

// Listens for activity on the button depending on its state
document.querySelector('[type="button"]').addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let choc = q("#choc");
    choc.innerHTML = "";

// Maxes out the values for height and length to 10 for practical reasons
    if (form.height.value > 10) form.height.value = 10;
    if (form.length.value > 10) form.length.value = 10;

    // assigns chocolate image to length and height
        for (let y = 0; y < form.height.value; y++) {
            let div = d.createElement("div");
            choc.appendChild(div);

            for (let x = 0; x < form.length.value; x++) {
                div.appendChild(q("#imgPos", q("template").content).cloneNode(true));
            }
        }
});

  function removeMe(e) {
    e.classList.remove("visible");
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#grid {
  top: 180px;
  left: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: auto;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 10px;
}
#imgPos {
  display: block;
  width : auto;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: auto;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#choc {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 240px;
  left: 340px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: default;
}

#choc > div{
  position: absolute;
  width:50px;
  display:block;
}

#choc > div > #imgPos{
  float: left;
  float: right;
  clear:none;
  width:50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#choc > div > #imgPos:not(.visible) {
    opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Here's a fiddle I made using it:

https://jsfiddle.net/p4ekmtgh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concat the id with variable x and y

```js
let child = q("#imgPos", q("template").content).cloneNode(true);
child.setAttribute("id","imgPos" + x + "_" + y);
div.appendChild(child);
```

css should also changed too

here is working fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/0fhykzmw/

Comment: already tried a similar solution, error is:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'cloneNode')"

Comment: Here is the working fidlle : https://jsfiddle.net/0fhykzmw/

Comment: worked for me! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line in your x ***for loop***.  `document.getElementById('imgPos').id = 'imgPos_' + x` this will concatenate the id with the value of X on each iteration.

```
for (let x = 0; x < form.length.value; x++) {
  div.appendChild(q("#imgPos", q("template").content).cloneNode(true));
  document.getElementById('imgPos').id = 'imgPos_' + x;
}
```

I also recommend making your css for the chocolate elements a class, so maybe add the class and its class attribute to the elements:

```
.imgPos {
  display: block;
  width : auto;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

...to each of the chocolate elements to style it, then change the ID to the unique numerical ID.

Comment: already found a solution but thanks a lot!